# Excel Formula to apply one formula to reference call and cells above and another formula to cells below

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure if this is possible via formula but I am trying to setup a formula that can be applied to a range of cells that will find the middle cell then apply one formula to all cells above it, another formula to the center cell and a different formula to all cells below. I figured out how to find that center cell but when I use an If neither of the conditions seem to be applied.
Here is what I have now...

```
    =IF(INDEX($H$4:$H$204,MATCH((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(((COUNTA($H$4:$H$204))/2)+4,9))),$H$4:$H$204,0)+1,1),0,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Let me know if this is what you're looking for:

```
=IF(ROW(A1)<ROUNDDOWN(COUNTA(A:A)/2,0),"formula 1",IF(ROW(A1)>ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A:A)/2,0),"formula 2","formula 3"))
```

The formula will work with both odd and even count of cells.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Justyna MK, That did it, although with all the dynamic stuff I have going on it too me awhile to get it working as intended. Here's what I came up with...
`=IF((ROW(G4)-4)<ROUNDDOWN(COUNTA($G$5:$G$204)/2,0),H5+(INDIRECT("G"&COUNTA(G:G))/(COUNTA($E$5:$E$204))),IF((ROW(G4)-4)>ROUNDUP(COUNTA($G$5:$G$204)/2,0),H3-(INDIRECT("G"&COUNTA(G:G))/(COUNTA($E$5:$E$204))),(-1*(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(((COUNTA($E$5:$E$204))/2)+4,7))))))`

Comment: Nice one! If the formula is too slow you can try replacing `INDIRECT` parts (these are volatile formulas) with `INDEX`, e.g. `INDEX(G:G,COUNTA(G:G))` instead of `INDIRECT("G"&COUNTA(G:G))`, or `INDEX(G:G,((COUNTA($E$5:$E$204))/2)+4)` instead of `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(((COUNTA($E$5:$E$204))/2)+4,7))`. But it looks like you already have everything sorted out :)